# C# delete row excel using OLEDB

Tags: c#

[image: error]

How to delete rows from an Excel sheet using OLEDB? I tried with **Delete from [Sheet1$]** but it's not working.

[image: excel file]

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string a1 = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source='" + textLoadFile.Text + "';Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;\"";
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(a1);
    //MessageBox.Show(dataGrid["STT", dataGrid.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString());
    conn.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = @"DELETE FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE STT = 2";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //docDL("Sheet1");
}
```

Comment: What is the format of the column in Excel (general, text, number)?  What is the connection string? Try IMEX=1 (see : https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/).   Column one is excel is considered a header row and sometimes gives issues.

Comment: How was table imported into excel? There is a link to the page (cell) that is giving an issue.